# Why would glDrawArrays result in EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)?

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-x

Why would the following line:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)numberOfVertices);
```

result in : `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)`

```
void Earth::onDraw(const cocos2d::Mat4 &transform, bool transformUpdated){
    Sprite *stripes = Sprite::create("stripes.png");
    this->setGLProgram(GLProgramCache::getInstance()->getGLProgram(GLProgram::GLProgram::SHADER_NAME_POSITION_TEXTURE));
    CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
    GL::bindTexture2D(stripes->getTexture()->getName());
    GL::enableVertexAttribs(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION | GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_TEX_COORD);
    DrawPrimitives::setDrawColor4F(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureCoordinates);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)numberOfVertices);
}
```

Earth is a cocos2d::Node.

Comment: Are you sure your context supports drawing from client memory (e.g. without a VBO)? Core contexts do not.

Comment: I don't know very much about OpenGL or cocos2d-x. I'm just trying to port code that works on cocos2d-iphone to cocos2d-x

Comment: Well, if it is trying to read from address **0** that is usually a sign that you are trying to do something involving a VBO, but do not actually have one bound when you setup your vertex pointers. And just looking at your code, I do not see a VBO bound either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the cocos2d-x documentation I found (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0beta2/d4/d83/group__shaders.html), `GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION` and `GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_TEX_COORD` are bitmask values, with values 1 and 4. But you use them as the first argument to `glVertexAttribPointer()`:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(GL::VERTEX_ATTRIB_FLAG_TEX_COORD, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureCoordinates);
```

The first argument here needs to be the location of the vertex attributes, which is unlikely to be 1 and 4. The way I interpret the documentation, you would need to use these values instead:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, textureCoordinates);
```

Comment: That solved the problem! There is a small error in your code though. It should be GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION and GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORDS